# making notification bar ("ticker") from my android application

Tags: android, facebook, permissions, notifications, ticker

I want to make update on the notification window on facebook , I think it's called ticker when someone finish a game on my application .

like:

Jesus Dimri made new record (10201 points) on super trivia !!

I don't want to make wallpost couse its to annoying to the user .

my application is connected with facebook but how do make it happen ??

again...no wallpost . just notify on notification  bar above the chat . like candycrush does and other applications.

Comment: is it like: user A installs your app, when other user get new thing, user A will get notification?

Comment: yep , like hige score and stuff like that . so when users play on the app it will promote the application in the ticker bar if thats what its called .

Comment: is there anything about the facebook? showing news of friends?

Comment: not that i have seen but maybe someone here will help me find the way to do that

Comment: can you poll your server at some interval to get new msgs, and show it in by notification?

Comment: didnt understood what you saying